# Typescript angular 1.x ui.router

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

Trying to write a ui.router in typescript for the first time. as of now my code looks like this:

```
class Configuration {
    constructor(private $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider, 
                private $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider) {
        this.init();
    }

    private init(): void {
        this.$stateProvider.state("main", Configuration.defaultState());
        this.$stateProvider.state("login", Configuration.login());
        this.$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
    }

    private static defaultState(): ng.ui.IState {
        return {
            url: "/main"
            , template: "<h1>hello</h1>"
        }
    }

    private static login(): ng.ui.IState {
        return {
            url: "/login"
            , template: "login"
        }
    }
}

angular.module('smm')
    .config(($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider, 
             $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider) => {
        return new Configuration($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
    });
```

As much as the compile code looks all right, the router does not seem to work, I have no error in the console nor any route is executed. I guess the problem is silly but I can't seem to find it. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me is your code working as is. There is **[a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LcrrAOLKCfbWxVW4zyqc?p=preview)** with your code as is.

This is the index.html

```
<html ng-app="smm" >

  <head>
    <title>my app</title>
    <style>ul { padding-left: 0; } li { list-style: none; }</style>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"
    ></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" 
            src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="Config.js"></script>
  </head> 

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/login">/login</a>
      <li><a href="#/main">/main</a>
    </ul>

    <div ui-view=""></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

This is script.js:

```
var app = angular
  .module('smm', [
    'ui.router' 
  ])
```

And content of the Config.js could be [found here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Configuration%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20%24stateProvider%3A%20ng.ui.IStateProvider%2C%20private%20%24urlRouterProvider%3A%20ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.init()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20init()%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24stateProvider.state(%22main%22%2C%20Configuration.defaultState())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24stateProvider.state(%22login%22%2C%20Configuration.login())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24urlRouterProvider.otherwise('%2Fmain')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20defaultState()%3A%20ng.ui.IState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%3A%20%22%2Fmain%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2C%20template%3A%20%22%3Ch1%3Ehello%3C%2Fh1%3E%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20login()%3A%20ng.ui.IState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%3A%20%22%2Flogin%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2C%20template%3A%20%22login%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aangular.module('smm')%0A%20%20%20%20.config((%24stateProvider%3A%20ng.ui.IStateProvider%2C%20%24urlRouterProvider%3A%20ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Configuration(%24stateProvider%2C%20%24urlRouterProvider)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B)

Check the working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LcrrAOLKCfbWxVW4zyqc?p=preview)

Note, with

```
<html ng-app="smm" ng-strict-di>
...
```

we would need:

```
angular.module('smm')
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
        return new Configuration($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
    }]);
```

Check that [forked version here](http://plnkr.co/edit/f5QQpMEDCjFO8gmWk2tA?p=preview), and [playground snippets here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Configuration%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20%24stateProvider%3A%20ng.ui.IStateProvider%2C%20private%20%24urlRouterProvider%3A%20ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.init()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20init()%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24stateProvider.state(%22main%22%2C%20Configuration.defaultState())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24stateProvider.state(%22login%22%2C%20Configuration.login())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24urlRouterProvider.otherwise('%2Fmain')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20defaultState()%3A%20ng.ui.IState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%3A%20%22%2Fmain%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2C%20template%3A%20%22%3Ch1%3Ehello%3C%2Fh1%3E%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20login()%3A%20ng.ui.IState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%3A%20%22%2Flogin%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2C%20template%3A%20%22login%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aangular.module('smm')%0A%20%20%20%20.config(%5B'%24stateProvider'%2C%20'%24urlRouterProvider'%2C%0A%09(%24stateProvider%2C%20%24urlRouterProvider)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Configuration(%24stateProvider%2C%20%24urlRouterProvider)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D)%3B)

Comment: awesome, thanks ... thought it was a stupid error from my side, lack of ```ui-view``` on the index .... sorry ... and thanks once again

Comment: If that helped, great! Enjoy amazing combination - Angular, Typescript and UI-Router ;)